# Can "-main-is" ghc's option be use via OPTIONS_GHC pragma?

Tags: haskell, ghc

Given `MyModule.hs`

```
$ cat MyModule.hs
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -main-is MyModule.main #-}

module MyModule where

main = print "MyModule.Main"
```

I can make an executable `app` with `-main-is` options

```
$ ghc -o app -main-is MyModule.main MyModule.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling MyModule         ( MyModule.hs, MyModule.o ) [flags changed]
Linking app ...
```

But when I ommit `-main-is` option and hope ghc will use `OPTIONS_GHC` pragma, it doesn't work.

```
$ ghc -o app MyModule.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling MyModule         ( MyModule.hs, MyModule.o )

<no location info>: error:
    output was redirected with -o, but no output will be generated
because there is no Main module.
```

The [document](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/flags.html#linking-options) mention `-main-is` as `dynamic` option type which mean it should be possible to use via the pragma [(ref)](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/using.html#command-line-options-in-source-files)

Question:

- Can `-main-is` be use via `OPTIONS_GHC` pragma?
- Did I use the pragma wrong way?

Comment: Based on some tests, I think it is more the combination with the `-o` flag.

Comment: `{-# OPTIONS_GHC -o app -main-is MyModule.main #-}` also failed too.

Comment: The `OPTIONS` pragma is for setting per-source file options, so it doesn't really make sense to use it to set a whole-program option. That being said, I would expect the compiler to at least issue a warning in this case (or the documentation to be more explicit about which options work here). Indeed, none of the linker options which apply to the whole program seem to work here (at least the ones I tried-about 5) which makes sense, because a "linker option" is not a "GHC option".

Comment: Furthermore, from a bit more testing, GHC is deliberately and silently discarding those options which it knows are invalid here (i.e. linker options). The docs claim "options given in the source file override those given on the command-line". But for example, when adding `-no-link` to `OPTIONS` doesn't do anything (in particular, an executable is still generated) but running `ghc -main-is MyModule.main -no-link MyModule.hs` will of course prevent the executable from being linked. (NB: if this is a real issue for you, I suggest opening a ticket)

Comment: The whole special way that GHC extracts file-level pragmas is a huge hack. This is one part of GHC that honestly makes me a bit sad. All this to say that this is probably not the intended behaviour - GHC is supposed to warn on unrecognized file-level options/pragmas.

Comment: Well it is quite odd that this is a "*dynamic*" flag, since there can only be one `main` module. What if two files would have such flag? The `-main-is` flag looks almost inherently static.